# Some questions about vs code emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code

Examples：
When I press the tab key

[image]

But I want it to appear with the following code，press the tab key

[image]

How to achieve my purpose？
thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with emmet that looks like yours.

How I fixed:

1. Go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**
2. Search for ***emmet expand abbreviation***
3. Edit the **keybinding** and set to **Tab** (again). It will show the column as "**User**" defined. Anyway it will fix.